# Having problem in understanding to update data in Dynamodb. I can't understand what is happening in this updateTodo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

**I have a lambda function which should update the field on dynamodb using AppSync. But i am having difficulty to understand the code. As I cant understand what is the purpose of the for loop and creating the variable "attributes" and the purpose of all those params and the prefix variable. Where as id the the primary key of my dynamo table**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

type Params = {
    TableName: string | undefined,
    Key: string | {},
    ExpressionAttributeValues: any,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: any,
    UpdateExpression: string,
    ReturnValues: string
}

async function updateTodo(todo: any) {
    let params: Params = {
        TableName: process.env.TODOS_TABLE,
        Key: {
            id: todo.id
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {},
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
        UpdateExpression: "",
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };


    let prefix = "set ";
    let attributes = Object.keys(todo);
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        let attribute = attributes[i];
        if (attribute !== "id") {
            params["UpdateExpression"] += prefix + "#" + attribute + " = :" + attribute;
            params["ExpressionAttributeValues"][":" + attribute] = todo[attribute];
            params["ExpressionAttributeNames"]["#" + attribute] = attribute;
            prefix = ", ";
        }
    }

    try {
        await docClient.update(params).promise()
        return todo
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('DynamoDB error: ', err)
        return null
    }
}


export default updateTodo;
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is building the required attributes for the [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) method.

Here's an example of what the parameters being passed to the `upateItem` method should look like:

```
const params = {
        TableName: "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
        Key: {
            "id": "1"
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set #attribute1 = :a1, #attribute2 = :a2",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#attribute1": "attribute1_name"
            "#attribute1": "attribute2_name"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":a1": "attribute 1 value",
            ":a2": "attribute 2 value"
        }
    };
```

The `updateTodo` method is building this parameter hash dynamically in several steps:

1. This block of code is creating a map called `params`.  It's specifying the table name by looking up the `TODOS_TABLE` environment variable.  The `Key` refers to the partition key, which in this example is named `id`.

```
    let params: Params = {
        TableName: process.env.TODOS_TABLE,
        Key: {
            id: todo.id
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {},
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
        UpdateExpression: "",
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
```

Notice how the `ExpressionAttributeValues`,`ExpressionAttributeNames` and `UpdateExpression` keys all have empty values.

2. The next step is to set the `params[ExpressionAttributeValues]` and `params[ExpressionAttributeNames]` as required by the [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) API.

```
 let prefix = "set ";
    let attributes = Object.keys(todo);
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        let attribute = attributes[i];
        if (attribute !== "id") {
            params["UpdateExpression"] += prefix + "#" + attribute + " = :" + attribute;
            params["ExpressionAttributeValues"][":" + attribute] = todo[attribute];
            params["ExpressionAttributeNames"]["#" + attribute] = attribute;
            prefix = ", ";
        }
    }
```

The end result is a `params` map that would look something like this:

```
const params = {
        TableName: "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
        Key: {
            "id": "1"
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set #attribute1 = :a1, #attribute2 = :a2",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#attribute1": "attribute1_name"
            "#attribute1": "attribute2_name"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":a1": "attribute 1 value",
            ":a2": "attribute 2 value"
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although one thing is still confusing me what is the purpose of For loop.

Comment: The for lop iterates through the todo attributes to build the UpdateExpression, ExpressionAttribureNames and ExpressionAttributeVales.  The todo variable is a map of attributes, like this { attribute1: "value1", attribute2: "value2"}. The for loop iterates over that data to build the update expressions